# How to combine mocha tests with mocha-phantomjs tests

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, phantomjs, mocha.js

Test cases:

- server/

  - appTest.js
- client/

  - clientTest.js
- clientBundle.js
- clientTest.html

All are mocha tests. For client tests, I use sinon, and webpack them to generate a bundle - clientBundle.js and run it using mocha-phantomjs for headless testing.

Now I have defined `npm test` as `mocha test/server && mocha-phantomjs test/clientTest.html`. It gives me results for both of them separately. How can I combine them into one - say `mocha test/all.js`.

Tried `require()s` inside `test/all.js`. mocha-phantomjs cannot be used as a library inside node. It can only be used as a CLI.